# Is there a way to find the closest element that isn't label and does not have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Giving an element, I need to find the closest element that isn't `label` and isn't an element that has a class of `radio` or `checkbox`

Here is what I have done

```
$parent = element.closest('div');

if($parent.hasClass('checkbox') || $parent.hasClass('radio'))
{
    $parent = $parent.parent();
}

error.appendTo($parent);
```

The above code works for the most part except it only looks for a `div` not any element.

Also, is there a shorter way to write this code where I can avoid the condition statement? Perhaps, use the `find()` method to search but not sure how to use it.

Here is the html code that I am trying to search

```
<div class="form-group  has-error">
    <label for="gender" class="col-md-2 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="gender_">
                <input id="gender_" required="1" name="gender" value="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="gender-error" type="radio">
                Please select your gender
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="gender_1">
                <input id="gender_1" required="1" name="gender" value="1" aria-required="true" type="radio">
                Male
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="gender_2">
                <input id="gender_2" required="1" name="gender" value="2" aria-required="true" type="radio">
                Female
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to appent to the div with the class "col-md-10".

Not it is not always a div or event the same class which is why I want to search for the closest element that isn't label of checkbox or radio class

Comment: `element.closest('div:not(label, .checkbox, .radio)')`

Comment: Now that you have the answer, I would like to recommend explaining what you are trying to accomplish as a whole because this seems like a pretty interesting way to get a handle to an element. There maybe a more efficient way if we know the whole scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:not(input, label, .checkbox, .radio)` in the `.closest()` selector. I've added the `input` because `.closest()` starts the check with the element it's been used on (the `input`).

**Note:** If you know that you are looking for an element with the `.col-md-10` class, you can use `.closest('.col-md-10')`.

```js
var result = $('input').closest(':not(input, label, .checkbox, .radio)');

console.log(result[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group  has-error">
    <label for="gender" class="col-md-2 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="gender_">
                <input id="gender_" required="1" name="gender" value="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="gender-error" type="radio">
                Please select your gender
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="gender_1">
                <input id="gender_1" required="1" name="gender" value="1" aria-required="true" type="radio">
                Male
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="gender_2">
                <input id="gender_2" required="1" name="gender" value="2" aria-required="true" type="radio">
                Female
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did not work. I updated my question with html code. in my case, the element is the input element and I need to identify the div with the class "col-md-10"

Comment: perfect! this is what I ended up with `$parent = element.closest(':not(input, label, .checkbox, .radio)').first();  
                        error.appendTo($parent);`  thank you very much